# asp.net mvc 4 razor custom html helper pass IEnumerable<model>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have strongly typed list view

I have custom html helper which must get `IEnumerable<object>`

does it possible to pass my model(`@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication2.Models.UserViewModel>`) to my html helper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your helper is defined like this:

```
public static IHtmlString SomeHelper(this HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<object>> html)
```

then it is **not possible** to call it like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication2.Models.UserViewModel>
@Html.SomeHelper()
```

If on the other hand it is defined like this:

```
public static IHtmlString SomeHelper(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<object> model)
```

you could call it from your view and pass the model:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication2.Models.UserViewModel>
@Html.SomeHelper(Model)
```

Comment: Hello Darin. You have helped me already in another question. On first method is gives such exception : No overload for method 'SomeHelper' takes 0 arguments. and second: No overload for method 'SomeHelper' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @Acid, it's normal about the first method. I said in my answer that you **cannot** use it. As far as the second one is concerned make sure that you have defined the helper signature exactly as I've shown and that you have brought the namespace in which this class is defined into scope in the view by adding the proper `using` directive.